# PHP PDO Exibir um unico registro

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Olá. Tenho um sistema de popup onde o cliente escolhe qual vai aparecer na home. Se um já estiver selecionado ele não pode selecionar outro. Tem que desmarcar o ativo e marcar o que ele deseja. Quero saber como colocar uma mensagem de aviso, avisando ele que já tem um ativo.

Segue o código:

```
$stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM comunicados"); 
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if($stmt->rowCount() > 1 ):
    echo "erro";
else:
// codigo se tudo estiver ok
endif;
```

Comment: Caro Betinho se é o que a pessoa selecionou então nem deveria vir do banco e sim de uma requisição HTTP (formulário), se é para impedir algo então não tem pq gravar no banco.

Comment: é vindo do banco... através do painel de controle. Olha esta imagem... https://i.ibb.co/CQrZW6c/Anota-o-2019-04-22-090111.png

Comment: Então o uso de banco não faz sentido ai, poderia ser resolvido via JavaScript no front-end, MAS dependente do que você fez, porque isso ai é um printscreen, nem dá para saber o que você fez e por isso não tem como eu ficar chutando respostas aqui. Recomendo que edite sua pergunta e explique melhor o que já tem.